# scroll_navigation in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, scroll, navigation

I'm working on a flutter project and I used scroll_navigation but I want to change    selectedItemColor and unselectedItemColor and I don't know how to change the color of the selected item in my scroll navigation.

```
@override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return ScrollNavigation(
        bodyStyle: NavigationBodyStyle(
          background: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.horizontal(left: Radius.circular(20)),
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        ),
        barStyle: NavigationBarStyle(
          position: NavigationPosition.left,
          elevation: 0.0,
          background: Colors.white,
        ),
        pages: [
          Container(color: Colors.blue[100]),
          Container(color: Colors.green[100]),
          Container(color: Colors.purple[100]),
          Container(color: Colors.amber[100]),
          Container(color: Colors.deepOrange[100])
        ],
        items: const [
          ScrollNavigationItem(icon: Icon(Icons.camera)),
          ScrollNavigationItem(icon: Icon(Icons.chat)),
          ScrollNavigationItem(icon: Icon(Icons.favorite)),
          ScrollNavigationItem(icon: Icon(Icons.notifications)),
          ScrollNavigationItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home))
        ],
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may set active and non-active colors via `NavigationBarStyle` like this:

```dart
barStyle: const NavigationBarStyle(
...
  activeColor: Colors.red,
  deactiveColor: Colors.yellow,
),
```

Comment: Please do you know how can I customize the bar height.

Comment: You may adjust the bar height by changing "verticalPadding" property.

Comment: Hello Please do you know how can I change background of selecteditem